# Different behavior of list selection in ie and firefox?

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser

```
<ul id='reorderps'>
<li><span><a href=''>+</a>Item 1</span></li>
 <ul>
   <li><span><a href=''>+</a>Sub Item 1</span></li>
   </ul>
 </ul>
```

I have a unordered list like this with level 1 and level 2 items when i am trying to do a

`jQuery('a').parent().parent().html();` it is behaving differently in ie. In IE it is taking ul below it as its child but in mozilla it isnt. What can be the cause and solution to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested in IE & Firefox, and in both it take same` +Item 1

Also you have missed brackets with first parent,I've tested like this for example

```
$("#reorderps").append(jQuery('a').parent().parent().html());
```

And in result I have this in both browsers

```
+Item 1
+Sub Item 1
+Item 1
```

Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sUxyt/1/

Why Item 1?Because jQuery('a') returns array to you, and jQuery('a') means `jQuery('a').eq(0)`

If you want to take next line you must write something kind of this

```
$("#reorderps").append(jQuery('a').eq(1).parent().parent().html());
```

In this situation you must get this in example of my jsfiddle

```
+Item 1
+Sub Item 1
+Sub Item 1
```

**EDIT:**

I change Javascript part as you want,like this

```
jQuery('ul#reorderps a').click(function(e){ alert(jQuery(this).parent().parent().html()); e.preventDefault(); });
```

And yeah, there is a difference in IE 7 & other browsers. All is need to change your html from this

```
<ul id='reorderps'>
<li><span><a href=''>+</a>Item 1</span></li>
 <ul>
   <li><span><a href=''>+</a>Sub Item 1</span></li>
   </ul>
 </ul>
```

to

```
<ul id='reorderps'>
<li><span><a href=''>+</a>Item 1</span></li>
    <li>
 <ul>
   <li><span><a href=''>+</a>Sub Item 1</span></li>
   </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

The reason of that behavior is that IE 7 doesn't recognize the end tag of your li, and take the innerHTML of your li little bit larger.
Adding li to second part solve the problem:)

Comment: That was by mistake actually it is parent().parent() and i am using ie7

Comment: What do you want to update? I make this jsfiddle to sow that your code has same behavior in both IE7 & Firefox.
You can run this code in both browsers and take a look to result.

Comment: i want to change the javascript to this i am not able to do it there here is the js please apply jQuery('ul#reorderps a').click(function(e){
    
    
   
    alert(jQuery(this).parent().parent().html());
    
    e.preventDefault();
    
    
});